# Open API 3.0.1 One Of Examples Definition in SpringBoot RestAPI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-codegen

I'm writing an OpenAPI spec for an existing API. This API returns status 400 for two different failure, but with a different response structure.I tried the following structure.

How to use oneOf example in OpenAPI 3.0.1 with Springboot Rest API?

```
    get:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Find pet by ID
      description: Returns a single pet
      operationId: getPetById
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          description: ID of pet to return
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
          content:
            application/json:
               schema:
                 oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResultOk'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResultError'
               examples:
                  success:
                    summary: Example of a Test response 1
                    value:
                      errorCode: "1001"
                      errorMsg: "Error Message 1"
                  error:
                    summary: Example of an error response 2
                    value:
                      errorCode: "1002"
                      errorMsg: "Error Message 2"
components:
  schemas:
    ApiResultOk:
      type: object
      properties:
        errorCode:
          type: string
        errorMsg:
          type: string
    ApiResultError:
      type: object
      properties:
        errorCode:
          type: string
        errorMsg:
          type: string
```

Edit :  After generated maven plugin and removed oneOf (single schema)

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Find pet by ID", nickname = "getPetById", notes = "Returns a single pet", authorizations = {
        
        @Authorization(value = "api_key")
         }, tags={ "pet", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid ID supplied", response = ApiResult.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Pet not found") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/ticketReOpen/{ticketUUID}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

public class ApiResult {

```
  @JsonProperty("errorCode")
  private String errorCode;

  @JsonProperty("errorMsg")
  private String errorMsg;

  public ApiResult errorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
  }

  public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  public ApiResult errorMsg(String errorMsg) {
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getErrorMsg() {
    return errorMsg;
  }

  public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
  }
```

}
Swagger UI doesnt display 400 code response and examples

Comment: What is the question exactly? Is there a problem with this definition, i.e. does it not work as expected?

Comment: In your example, the `ApiResultOk` and `ApiResultError` schemas are exactly the same (i.e. have the same properties) so you don't actually need `oneOf` and two schemas. Just use a single `ApiResult` schema without `oneOf`.

Comment: Swagger UI doesnt display 400 code response and examples, even though I generate it with the changes you wrote.